# Configuring certificate signing for development and production environments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ssl, entity-framework-core

The below code works but there's a lot of duplication I wonder if I can get around.

I would like to be able to use `.AddDeveloperSigningCredential(false)` if in development environment, otherwise set a certificate collection object and use `.AddSigningCredential(certCollection[0])`

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<RSNROAuthContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RSNRAccountDB")));

        services.AddScoped(typeof(IUserProfileRepository), typeof(UserProfileRepository));

        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(config =>
            {
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RSNROAuthContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

        services.AddMvc();

        string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("RSNRAccountDB");

        X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        if (Env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
            services.AddIdentityServer()

                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential(false)
                .AddAspNetIdentity<User>()
                // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly("RSNR.OAuth.DAL"));
                })
                // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly("RSNR.OAuth.DAL"));

                    // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                    options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
                })
                .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
            }
        else
        {
            X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, Configuration["WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES"], false);

            // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddSigningCredential(certCollection[0])

                .AddAspNetIdentity<User>()
                // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly("RSNR.OAuth.DAL"));
                })
                // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly("RSNR.OAuth.DAL"));

                    // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                    options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
                })
                .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

        }

            services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
            services.Configure<ClientOptions>(Configuration);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of repeated code in the `if` and the `else` branch which can be extracted. Assuming the `services.XXX()` methods are using fluent style and every call returns a `IServiceCollection` it could look like so

```
    IIdentityServerBuilder serverBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer();

    if (Env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
            serverBuilder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential(false);
    }
    else
    {
        X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, Configuration["WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES"], false);

        // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
        serverBuilder.AddSigningCredential(certCollection[0]);
    }

    serverBuilder.AddAspNetIdentity<User>()
    // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
    .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
            builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly("RSNR.OAuth.DAL"));
    })
    // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
    .AddOperationalStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
            builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly("RSNR.OAuth.DAL"));

        // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
        options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
        options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
    })
    .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion however the likes of AddSigningCredential needs to chain on to AddIndentityServer() - otherwise I get could not resolve symbol syntax error on AddSigningCredential etc.

Comment: So what does `AddIdentityServer()` return ?

Comment: if I peek the definition, it says: `public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddIdentityServer(this IServiceCollection services);`

Comment: And what returns `AddDeveloperSigningCredential()` and `AddSigningCredential()` ?

Comment: `public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddDeveloperSigningCredential(this IIdentityServerBuilder builder, bool persistKey = true, string filename = null);` and `public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddSigningCredential(this IIdentityServerBuilder builder, X509Certificate2 certificate);`

Comment: Should work now

Comment: A slight tweak was needed - please review my edits and I will accept. You're a pro! Thank you!

Comment: I have edited the answer. Unfortunately your edit had been rejected by other users while I had been left the office.

Comment: I feel this community can be particularly harsh on newcomers. My edit was valid, although I understand yours is better, so it is welcome. Thank you for your help and patience. I have certainly learned from it.